# How to access a variable declared inside IF statement outside IF statement in Python

Tags: python, mysql, variables, flask, mysql-connector

I'm trying to use `searchData` outside my if statement so I could use the variable inside my query. but it gives me an error of `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'searchData' referenced before assignment`

```
@app.route('/ML', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
  if request.method == "POST":
        request_data = json.loads(request.data)
        searchData = (request_data['content'])
        return jsonify(searchData)
  mycursor = mydb.cursor(dictionary=True)
  query = "SELECT * FROM COMPANY WHERE COMPANY_NAME LIKE %s LIMIT 20;"
  mycursor.execute(query,("%" + searchData + "%",))
  myresult = mycursor.fetchall()

  company = []
  content = {}

  for result in myresult:
     content ={'COMPANY_NAME':result['COMPANY_NAME'],}
     company.append(content)
     content = {}
  return jsonify(company)
```

I've also tried declaring `searchData` just above my if statement. it removes the error but the value isn't changed by my if statement. It stays just how I declared it. I appreciate any help anyone could give. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Does request.method always equal POST?

Comment: @Programmer No, My frontend will also fetch from the function once it has passed data to my python backend

Comment: If request.method is not always POST, the variable searchedInput might not always be declared.

Comment: @Programmer what can you suggest to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that this problem can be alleviated by the `global` treatment to the variable. How about declaring the searchData as global first?

```
@app.route('/ML', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
  global searchData
  if request.method == "POST":
        request_data = json.loads(request.data)
        searchData = (request_data['content'])
        return jsonify(searchData)
  mycursor = mydb.cursor(dictionary=True)
  query = "SELECT * FROM COMPANY WHERE COMPANY_NAME LIKE %s LIMIT 20;"
  mycursor.execute(query,("%" + searchData + "%",))
  myresult = mycursor.fetchall()

  company = []
  content = {}

  for result in myresult:
     content ={'COMPANY_NAME':result['COMPANY_NAME'],}
     company.append(content)
     content = {}
  return jsonify(company)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a `return searchedInput` statement in `if` statement block, removing it may solve your problem. `return` statement will terminates your function execution.

For `GET` method, `searchedInput` should declared before `if` statement.

Comment: Hello I added some more code to specify my problem a bit more. Should I add a fetch statement for GET too?

Comment: if `searchedData` is used both by POST and GET, it should be declared before `if` statement